# iPhone App rejected because of Three20 private API undocumented, private UITouch instance variables:

Tags: iphone, objective-c, three20, appstore-approval

I got a notification mail after submitting my iphone application  to apple store..

"During our review of your application we found it is using private APIs, which is in violation of the iPhone Developer Program License Agreement section 3.3.1; "3.3.1 Applications may only use Documented APIs in the manner prescribed by Apple and must not use or call any private APIs." While your application has not been rejected, it would be appropriate to resolve this issue in your next update.

The non-public APIs that are included in your application are the following undocumented, private UITouch instance variables:

> firstResponder
>   UITouch._locationInWindow
>
> UITouch._phase
>
> UITouch._previousLocationInWindow
>
> UITouch._tapCount
>
> UITouch._timestamp
>
> UITouch._touchFlags
>
> UITouch._view
>
> UITouch._window

Please resolve this issue in your next update to Application " .

My application contains Three20. These variables are used in "UIViewAdditions.m". Is there any way to resolve this issue ? Please help me. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Update your copy of Three20 to the latest version (P31), which has this problem resolved.

Answer (score 3):

p31 is a forked branch.  You can go that way if you wish, but [three20](http://github.com/facebook/three20) also has the updates.